# breezejs angularjs ToDo SPA template in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, angularjs, breeze, single-page-application

I have a question about design. I've just been through the code of the ToDo template of Visual Studio for building a SPA with BreezejS and AngularJS.

There is a todo.model.js file that do various initialization. One interesting thing is that it extends the TodoList Entity with some  additional function (addToDo).

What is the advantage of doing so, over having the addToDo function in the todo.controller instead and adding it to the $scope ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a good case for moving all of the `TodoList` level persistence operations out of the  TodoList and into some other component. The controller is a potential candidate.

The primary reason that these operations are in the `TodoList` is ... because that's where the authors of the original ASP.NET template put them!

One of the "*community template*" design goals was for all of the "TodoList" apps to be as similar to each other as possible. By holding the design constant we made it easier for readers to compare the effect of the different frameworks: Knockout, Breeze, Backbone, Ember. Had any of them relocated these operations, you would not know if that change was imposed by the target framework or was simply the the implementer's preference. We wanted to take our ego out of it and let you concentrate on the technologies involved.

**Don't treat these templates as gospel**. In some respects they are unrealistic; I can't imagine saving every time a single property of a single object changes.

Learn from them. Regard them with healthy skepticism. Keeping asking questions like this one. Take what make sense to you. Discard the rest.

Comment: great answer :) I agree on every point but I just wanted to make sure by asking for some other opinions. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is just letting the entity handle its own save/delete functions for items in the list.  The controller seems to be handling only adding of new lists.  I'm not sure there's any advantage other than keeping the controller clean.